# How do I change a sprite's color?

Tags: opengl, sprites, color

In my rhythm game, I have a note object which can be of a different color depending on the note chart. I could use a sprite sheet with all the different color variations I use, but I would prefer to parametrize this.
(Each note sprite is made of different shades of a hue. For example a red note has only red, light red and dark red.)

How can I colourise a sprite anew?

I'm working with OpenGL, but any algorithm or math explanation will do. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd probably use a single color image (eg. your note-sprite) with alpha channel and then color the whole image with your base-color. So, something like in the following image ([from wikimedia commons](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:1-8_note_quaver_%28music%29.svg)):

[image: image of a music-note]

If your color was red, you would then color the note (all the black parts) with the same red. What you would need in addition, is a grayscale image with the shading of the note. Then combine the shading with the flat color by using [blend-modes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blend_modes) like *Multiply* and/or *Screen*.

Another, probably simpler approach would be to just have a grayscale image where you would multiply each color component with your selected color. So if you have a gray value of `0.5`, and a red color `RGB(1.0, 0.0, 0.0)`, that would result in `RGB(0.5, 0.0, 0.0)` for the given pixel.

**Update:** Here's an example image to illustrate what I mean with the blend-modes:

[image: blending layers]

Of course you could just use the *shadow* layer if you don't need the highlights (which is basically the same as the simpler approach mentioned above).

Comment: This is so off-topic but I got to ask - how did you make that second image?

Comment: @DMan Photoshop for the different note images and then Illustrator to arrange stuff ;)

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. :)
Is it possible to do the blend into a fragment shader ? Or is it preferable to stay with the opengl blend function and render the 3 images separately ?

Comment: I'm not a shader expert, but from my limited knowledge I'd say it shouldn't be a problem. Alternatively you could just pre-calculate the images you need on the CPU?

Comment: Yes, for the moment I will generate a sprite sheet with all the variations.

Answer (score 3):

Make a greyscale (or just white) version of the image you want to show, with a suitable alpha channel. Use the vertex color to "dye" the image.

Vertex color multiplies each channel, so white x red = red, 50% grey x red = 50% red, and so on.

Comment: Problem with this is that the shading won't be recognizable when using bright colors (for example yellow).

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Black or very dark grey in the greyscale image multiplied by very bright yellow is still black or very dark yellow.

Comment: BTW, I'm sorry, I hadn't seen the "probably simpler approach" in your answer.

Comment: You're right about the multiplying. I was mixing things up. Lack of coffee I guess.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but as I'm learning opengl 3 I'd prefer to use the other method. :)

Comment: Very late to this, but I worked out a solution that works with both bright and dark colours. It also allows parts of the Sprite to keep original colours. Basically, if input colour is not grayscale (r=g=b), just output it unchanged. Otherwise, check if r(or g or b) is less than 0.5f. If less, multiply input colour and vertex colour and double that. For bright colours (r>0.5), multiply input and vertex, then subtract a 50%gray. This colorizes grayscale images in a way that looks natural. Black stays black, white stays white and middle gray is exactly the vertex colour.